# How can I run simultaneously two different JVM in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: java

I need run two Java applications simultaneously but each one use requires different Java version. My default Java is 1.8, but I need to run one of the applications with version 1.6. Is there a way of config the two versions simultaneously?

The applications are:

- Oracle JDeveloper 12.2.1.2.0 (JDK 1.8)
- Oracle JDeveloper 11.1.1.6.0 (JDK 1.6)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Assuming you've already got 1.8 installed:

Download the 1.6 `.tar.gz` file from Oracle's website, and extract it to a location of your choice such as `/opt/jdk1.6/`.

After you've done that, you can just do:

```
#For the app that requires 1.8
java -jar program.jar

#For the app that requires 1.6
/opt/jdk1.6/bin/java -jar program.jar
```